# Limit File upload Size in Gerrit

Tags: git, gerrit

How can I limit the file upload size in gerrit and make sure no one will upload binary files.Is there a way to do it in gerrit ?

I think there should be some settings which we can configure in gerrit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the [CheckFile](https://metacpan.org/pod/Git::Hooks::CheckFile) module of the [Git-Hooks](https://metacpan.org/release/Git-Hooks). It's very powerful and configurable. Really nice.

Answer (score 3):

You can configure it in Gerrit web UI [per Project](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/project-configuration.html#_maximum_git_object_size_limit) or globally [per Gerrit instance](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/config-gerrit.html#receive.maxObjectSizeLimit) in Gerrit server configuration file.